# Read from file into an object

Tags: java, string, io, bufferedreader

I want to be able to take the first 3 lines of a text file and use each line as a separate parameter. For example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
    try {
                File file = new File("test.txt");
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                    stringBuffer.append("\n");
                }
                fileReader.close();
                System.out.println("Contents of file:");
                System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is how I currently read from file, so if I have an object called address that looks at the first three lines of a textfile and gets street name, city, country, how would I read each line and set them to a parameter for a new Address object?

```
Address test = new Address(String sname, String city, String country)
```

is my example constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep those 3 lines in a `String` array, and then call them using indices:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String[] lines = new String[3];
        int i = 0;
        while ((lines[i] = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if ( i == 2 ) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        fileReader.close();
        Address test = new Address(lines[0], lines[1], lines[2]);
        // do something with test
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where

- `lines[0]` = street name
- `lines[1]` = city
- `lines[2]` = country

---

According to your comment, if you want to have multiple addresses:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        int noOfAddresses = lines.size() - lines.size() % 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfAddresses; i += 3) {
            addresses.add(new Address(lines.get(i), lines.get(i + 1), lines.get(i + 2)));
        }
        // do something with addresses 
        // (Example - print them, if you defined toString in Address class)
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < addresses.size() ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println(addresses.get(i));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Steps:

1. Create a new list that will store the lines (`lines`)
2. Create a new list that will store the `Address` objects (`addresses`)
3. Read all lines, and add them to `lines` list.
4. Probably this line is tricky:

   ```
   int noOfAddresses = lines.size() - lines.size() % 3;
   ```

   It ignores the last 0, 1 or 2 lines that are not needed if you want to have a correct address (with no `null` street, city and country).
5. Then, the first 3 lines are used for the first address, the next 3 lines for the second address, etc. This is why I used `i += 3` there.

Comment: Hmmm, okay thanks! How hard would it be to incorporate other 3 lines segments, so if there are 21 lines (7 object params) how would I incorporate this? just make a string array and find a way to loop that?

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you to use [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) or other equivalent technology for serializing/deserializing java objects.